# Nestjs transform JSON arra as string[]

Tags: nestjs, class-transformer

I have the following get request:
`/api?entitiesText=["america", "americans"]&phrasesText=["a month-long effort"]`

I want to transform `entitiesText` and `phrasesText` to `string[]`:

```
export class ContentEnrichmentQuery {
    @IsArray()
    entitiesText?: string[];

    @IsArray()
    phrasesText?: string[];
}
```

This is the method:

```
@Get('/toppings')
async getViaPost(@Query(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })) contentEnrichmentQuery: ContentEnrichmentQuery) {....}
```

Right now I get them as `string` and not `string[]`

Comment: try doing `/api?entitiesText[]=america&entitiesText[]=americans&phrasesText[]=a month-long effort`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL and Query parameters will always come in as strings. That's how the underlying HTTP adapters and parsing packages work. If you want them to be non-string values you'll need to add a custom `@Transform()` decorator to these, like `@Transform({value} => JSON.parse(value))`